# yarn -v , nodejs -v and other command don't output nothing : 0 line

Tags: package-management, users, binary

I have a dedicates serveur with ubuntu 14 and plesk on it (not my choice).

I could launch without problem from my admin user:

```
cmeneux@sd-111960:~$ yarn -v
1.22.5
cmeneux@sd-111960:~$ npm -v
6.14.8
cmeneux@sd-111960:~$ nvm version
v14.15.0
cmeneux@sd-111960:~$ nodejs -v
The program 'nodejs' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install nodejs
cmeneux@sd-111960:~$ node -v
v14.15.0
```

**Here is the problem :**
With each domain we create we have a specific user created, with some **ssh bin/bash** credential.

If I log ssh with this user (here christian):

```
christian@sd-111960:~$ yarn -v
christian@sd-111960:~$ node -v
christian@sd-111960:~$ npm -v
The program 'npm' is currently not installed
```

As you could see there isn't any output of `yarn -v node -v`.
And I want this user to be able to launch these commands.

If we focus on yarn, the binary are at the same place :

```
christian@sd-111960:~$ which yarn
/usr/bin/yarn

lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          22 Aug 27 13:16 yarn -> ../share/yarn/bin/yarn
```

So it look like the user as the permission to access it, I don't know where look deeper to solve this issue.
Same thing for node ( not nodejs), same permission, locate in /usr/sbin/node .

I try to &>debug.log but really nothing output, that's what disturb me. I don't understand what going on and how investigate more ...

A strange thing :
I **install everything from my admin** ssh session ('cmeneux') : apt get apt update etc..
If I look for npm from this session :

```
cmeneux@sd-111960:~$ which npm
/home/cmeneux/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.0/bin/npm
```

Obviously it seems that the other session 'christian' doesn't access to this bin.
Maybe I'm wrong when I install it :
history from my admin ssh :

```
  333  curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
  334  echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
  335  sudo apt update && sudo apt install yarn
  336  sudo apt install yarn
```

For info :

```
christian@sd-111960:/usr/sbin$ $PATH
-bash: /opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin:/var/www/vhosts/sd-111960.dedibox.fr/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games: No such file or directory


cmeneux@sd-111960:~$ $PATH
-bash: /home/cmeneux/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games: No such file or directory
```

Thanks for your help and comment,

Comment: Ubuntu 14 is EOL, unsupported.

Comment: Great information :D